# Llamar evento click

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Quiero mandar a llamar este evento con `JavaScript`

```
protected void newButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "ModalGood();", true);
            Button Btnclick = (Button)sender;
            var team = Btnclick.Text;
            string name = Btnclick.CommandArgument;

            List.ListUsers listArea = new List.ListUsers();
            List<Data.Area> Area = listArea.AreaList();

            List<Data.Area> ListOfToolsOk = Area.Where(x => x.AREA == team && x.TEAM == team && x.STANDBY == 0).ToList();

            var ToolArea = ListOfToolsOk.Select(x => x.TEAM);
            Grv_Eng.DataSource = ListOfToolsOk;
            Grv_Eng.DataBind();
        }
```

pasandole el elemento `sender` tomando en cuenta que el id del boton que ejecuta ese evento es dinamico.

¿Es Posible hacerlo con `JavaScript`?

Comment: como llamas a ese evento, mediante el atributo OnClick?

Comment: @JuanManuelGaravitoFacundo al momento de crear el boton le coloco `newButton.Click += new EventHandler(newButton_Click);` pero tomando en cuenta que lo quiero por medio de un `javascript` lo coloco asi `newButton.OnClientClick = "newButton_Click";`

Comment: Has probado con mi respuesta? para saber si debo corregirla o no

Comment: @JuanManuelGaravitoFacundo  Si la he tomado en cuenta pero de igual manera tomando en cuenta que el id es diferente para los botones que quiero que ejecuten el mismo evento no la puedo usar

Comment: En tu caso yo dejaría todo de lado del cliente... osea los eventos de los botones de lado cliente, solo javascript... y la parte del ASP.NET en el mismo click desde Javascript llamaría un AJAX para una función en ASP.NET que hiciera lo que debe hacer del lado del SERVER, me parece muy rebuscado que quieras que el click de javascript llame al evento click del SERVER, pon los botones y funciones de lado cliente, llama al server cuando tengas que hacerlo, es solo mi opinión.

Answer (score 1):

con jquery seria :

```
<a class="t" id="dynamic"></a> 

$(".t").click(function(e){
  newButton_Click($(this),e)
})
```

si no quiere usar jquery

```
document.getElementsByClassName("t").addEventListener('click', function(e){
  newButton_Click(document.getElementsByClassName("t"),e)
})
```

La idea es que si el ID es dinamico usar otro atributo que no lo sea para poder consultar el DOM

Comment: trate con el ejemplo de jquery y me arrojo este error al ejecutar el programa `JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'`

Comment: No creo que sea la respuesta... newButton_Click es un evento de ASP.NET no de JAVASCRIPT....  :S

Answer (score 0):

Bueno, lo que yo haria seria lo siguiente:

El boton seria algo asi:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="newButton" Text="" style="display:none;" OnClick="newButton_Click" />
```

y en Javascript esto, dentro de la funciono evento donde lo necesites:

```
document.getElementById("btnSample").click();
```

Comment: No creo que sea la respuesta, lo que quiere es que dinamicamente desde JavaScript se llame el evento de asp.net según el botón que le des click, una lógica algo redundante y compleja... pero lo que tu propones es solo como hacer que un BOTON FIJO no dinámico llame un evento de ASP.NET y uno de Javascript

Answer (score -2):

Para capturar el evento pasandole todos los datos seria de la siguiente forma:

```js
function clickHandler(e, v) {
 
  console.log(e, v);
  // e es el evento
  // v es el boton

}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Handling click event </title>
    <meta charset="utf8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="clickHandler(event, this)"> Click me!!! </button>
  </body>
<html>
```